# Wait for Subscription set Recursively to Complete

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have an array of objects with children and have a need to set a field (hidden) in each of those objects recursively. The value for each is set in a subscription. I want to wait until each item in the array is recursively updated before the subscription is complete.

The hidden field will be set based on roles and permissions derived from another observable. In the example I added a delay to simulate that.

Here's my first pass at it. I'm certain there is a much cleaner way of going about this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-playground-hp3wr

```
// Array structure. Note children.
const navigation = [
  {
    id: "applications",
    title: "Applications",
    children: [
      {
        id: "dashboard",
        title: "Dashboard"
      },
      {
        id: "clients",
        title: "Clients"
      },
      {
        id: "documents",
        title: "Documents",
        children: [
          {
            id: "dashboard",
            title: "Dashboard"
          },...
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "reports",
        title: "Reports"
      },
      {
        id: "resources",
        title: "Resources"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

In the code sandbox example, looking at the console messages, I get the correct result. However, I would like to avoid having to subscribe in setHidden and recursivelySetHidden. I would also like to avoid using Subject if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```js
const roleObservable = timer(1000).pipe(mapTo("**************"));

function populateWithField(o, field, fieldValue) {
  if (Array.isArray(o)) {
    return from(o).pipe(
      concatMap(c => populateWithField(c, field, fieldValue)),
      toArray()
    );
  }

  if (o.children) {
    return roleObservable.pipe(
      tap(role => (fieldValue = role)),
      concatMap(role => populateWithField(o.children, field, role)),
      map(children => ({
        ...o,
        [field]: fieldValue,
        children
      }))
    );
  }

  return roleObservable.pipe(
    map(role => ({
      [field]: role,
      ...o
    }))
  );
}

of(navigation)
  .pipe(concatMap(o => populateWithField(o, "hidden")))
  .subscribe(console.log, e => console.error(e.message));
```

The main thing to notice is the frequent use of [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap). It it a [higher-order mapping operator](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) which means, among other things, that it will automatically subscribe to/unsubscribe from its inner observable.

What differentiates `concatMap` from other operators, is that it **keeps a buffer** of emitted values, which means that it will **wait** for the **current inner observable** to complete before subscribing to the next one.

In this case, you'd have to deal with a lot of Observables-of-Observables(`higher-order observables`), which is **why** you have to use `concatMap` every time you encounter a `children` property. Any child in that property could have their own `children` property, so you must make sure an Observable contains **only** **first-order** Observables.

You can read more about higher-order and first-order observables [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/higher-order-observable/).

[Here is a CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-playground-rq7rr)

Comment: Thank you. That helped!